# Telerik OpenAccess. Using other type of collection instead of IList<T>

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-open-access

I created a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>` and wanted to use it instead of `IList<T>`. When I modified the generator to generate `ObservableCollection<T>` or `MyCollectionClass<T>`(inherits `ObservableCollection<T>`) it gives this error:

> *'MyCollectionClass' does not contain a definition for 'Customer' and no extension method 'Customer' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'MyCollectionClass' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Does anyone faced this problem before? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In case you read this, can you tell me what you did? P.S: This is why you include the answer along with the link, as off-site resources can get deleted (like in the case of your proposed answer)

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in the meantime so adding the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering to my own question: I created my own collection class and made it inherit from TrackedBindingList and implemented INotifyCollectionChanged. That took care of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TrackedBindingList`, however when you do that you have to provide data type of the collection items.

```
companies.HasAssociation<Customer>(c => c.Customer)
    .WithOpposite(c => c.Company)
    .HasConstraint((c,​cc) => c.ID == cc.CustomerID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could troubleshoot the issue on your side using the information listed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/angelsb/archive/2007/02/23/does-not-contain-a-definition-for.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4aad8at%28vs.80%29.aspx).